# Установка javax

Tags: java, java-ee

Проблема вот в чем: нужно написать приложение Java EE, но отсутствует javax. Откуда его можно взять и как его установить? На моём компьютере установлена Java EE, а на ноутбуке - только Java SE. Сегодня я с помощью подключаемых модулей установил Java EE и сервер Glassfish, но это не решило проблему ввиду отсутствия javax.

Comment: Сергей, далеко вам еще до "нужно". Вам пока еще на первую ступень знаний по теме Java надо перейти, почитать первые главы любого учебника по теме, чтобы потом, даже с высоты этой первой ступени понять, почему ваш вопрос, скажем так, не вполне адекватен. Не поймите неправильно.

Comment: Вы вместо того, чтобы писать всякие глупости, ответили бы "что" и "как", и что в моем вопросе неадекватного, но, видимо, переход на первую ступень завышает ЧСВ до бесконечности.

Comment: Сергей, голодному не рыба нужна, а удочка.

Пусть будет рыба: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html

Здесь про JavaEE и javax.
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaEE#API_.D0.B2_Java_EE

Теперь насчет почему "неадекватен": Смысл выражения "отсутствие javax" невозможно расшифровать. Где отсутствует? В инсталляции? В проекте, который вы пишете, потому что Eclipse красным подчеркивает?
А версия Java вообще какая?

Если пишете проект, то сначала создаете New->Server, где настроите своа затем в самом проекте (Properties) ищете Targeted Runtime

Comment: Я понимаю, почему мой вопрос может быть глупым, но до этого я не сталкивался с подобным и в данных тонкостях ни разу не силен. Я использую NetBeans, он подчеркивает любой import package javax.* красным и указывает, что данный пакет не существует. Я вежлив, можно было написать, что вопрос неконкретен, а не неадекватен. Это разные вещи. И не нужно мне предлагать скачать EE.

Comment: Нет, просто неверна постановка вопроса. Я не зря написал "почитать первые главы любого учебника по теме" (заметьте, не по Java, а по теме).

Подчеркивает, потому что в Java Build Path проекта не присутствует путь до нужных библиотек (это уже из базовых понятий Java - не только к javax относится).

Либо на Properties->Libraries->Add Library
либо
New Project->JavaEE->Enterprise Application Next, затем в пункте "3" добавьте сервер. В этом случае IDE добавит все сам.

Comment: В jdk8 (java se) пакет javax точно есть. Помимо всего прочего, там  ещё и пакет swing лежит

Answer (score 0):

Я заметил, что библиотеки *Javax* подтягиваются с *Hibernate* или возможно *JDBC*. Если вы работаете с *Hibernate*, явно будете работать и с *JDBC*, то у вас импорты начнут работать. Отдельно *Javax* ещё не грузил.

Не забывайте установить галочку: "Enable annotation processing".

Answer (score 0):

Если в проекте используете Maven, то просто в зависимости добавьте нужную библиотеку из http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax

Comment: А если  Maven не используется?